# How to find total duration of time in power bi?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have time format in text as a table in Power bi.

[image: Table]

I want to find total duration of time by adding all time together in days, hours, minutes, seconds
Something like this:-

[image: Result]

How can I write Dax for this?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Is your time format > hr:mm:ss?

Comment: yes ..  format is greater than 24 hours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you already excepted my first answer, I wants to let you know about another option. I am posting it as separate answer as I do not wants to mess between two answer.

You can also do the whole thing using DAX without steps I have explained in my earlier answer. You can do it directly from list of value like-

[image]

The DAX query is(bit big but you can make a try)-

```
total_seconds_dax = 

var total_second = 
SUMX(
    total_time,
    INT(
        MID(
            total_time[Time],
            1,
            SEARCH(":",total_time[Time],1,0) - 1
        )
    )
) * 60 * 60
+
SUMX(
    total_time,
    INT(
        MID(
            total_time[Time],
            SEARCH(":",total_time[Time],1,0) + 1,
            SEARCH(
                ":",
                total_time[Time],
                SEARCH(":",total_time[Time],1,0) + 1
               ,0
            ) 
            - 
            (SEARCH(":",total_time[Time],1,0) + 1)
        )
    )
) * 60
+
SUMX(
    total_time,
    INT(
        MID(
            total_time[Time],
            SEARCH(
                ":",
                total_time[Time],
                SEARCH(":",total_time[Time],1,0) + 1
                ,0
            ) + 1 
            ,
            LEN(total_time[Time]) - 
            SEARCH(
                ":",
                total_time[Time],
                SEARCH(":",total_time[Time],1,0) + 1
                ,0
            )
        )
    )
)

var DayCount = INT(total_second/(24*60*60))
var HoursCount = MOD(INT(total_second/(60*60)),24)
var MinCount   = MOD(INT(total_second/60),60)
var SecCount   = MOD(total_second,60)

RETURN DayCount & " Days & " & HoursCount & " Hours & " & MinCount & " Minutes & " & SecCount & " Seconds"
```

Comment: Hey @mkRabbani I have modified your second solution that you have given. I have reduced the size of Dax by using some text functions. Just have a look

Comment: I saw that. But for that, you have to make sure the value always contains 2 char for hour, 2 char for min and 2 char for second. Other case, this will not work. Thinking this, I went for a long but dynamic solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
total_duration_dax_2 = 

var total_second = 
SUMX(
    TIME2,
    INT(
        VALUE(LEFT(TIME2[Table2],2))
        
    )
) * 60 * 60
+
SUMX(
    TIME2,
    INT(
        VALUE(MID(TIME2[Table2],4,2))
    )
) * 60
+
SUMX(
    TIME2,
    INT(
        VALUE(RIGHT(TIME2[Table2],2))
        
    )
)

var DayCount = INT(total_second/(24*60*60))
var HoursCount = MOD(INT(total_second/(60*60)),24)
var MinCount   = MOD(INT(total_second/60),60)
var SecCount   = MOD(total_second,60)

RETURN DayCount & " Days & " & HoursCount & " Hours & " & MinCount & " Minutes & " & SecCount & " Seconds"
```

The result is same

Answer (score 0):

If your input values are representing "HH:mm:ss" format, you can perform following steps to achieve your required output.

**Step-1**: After loading your data, duplicate your "time" column and then split the column as shown in the below image using delimiter ":"

[image]

The output of above action will be as below. Please rename column names as Hour, Minute and Second. Also change data type of those columns as number/whole number.

[image]

**Step-2**: Add a custom column with script-

```
total_second = 
([Hour] * 60 * 60)
+ ([Minute] *60)
+ ([Second])
```

The output will be as below with total seconds per row-

[image]

**Step-3**: Go back to report by applying the changes.

**Step-4**: Create a Measure as below-

```
custom_second_to_day = 

var DayCount = INT(total_time[m_total_second]/(24*60*60))
var HoursCount = MOD(INT(total_time[m_total_second]/(60*60)),24)
var MinCount   = MOD(INT(total_time[m_total_second]/60),60)
var SecCount   = MOD(total_time[m_total_second],60)

RETURN DayCount & " Days & " & HoursCount & " Hours & " & MinCount & " Minutes & " & SecCount & " Seconds"
```

The final output of the Measure will be - "**2 Days & 21 Hours & 56 Minutes & 51 Seconds**"